# javascript: display a <div> block only if a variable has certain value

Tags: javascript, django

I want to display a `<div>` section in my html file only if a variable(passed from a django view) equals "abc". I sort of think that javascript can be of help here but not sure how- new to both. How can this be achieved?

Comment: 3 second search is enough to encounter with an example code: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_toggle_hide_show.asp

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this directly from the template without involving javascript on the client.

```
{% if var == 'abc' %}
     <div>Rendered!</div>
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to be able to toggle this `div`, you could use the variable to set an attribute value, and with an attribute selector, use CSS to display it.

Maybe something like this

```
<div data-showme="{% if var == 'abc' %}true{% endif %}">Hi there</div>
```

Stack snippet

```css
div[data-showme] {
  display: none;
}

div[data-showme='true'] {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div data-showme="true">Hi there</div>

<div data-showme="">Hi there back (hidden)</div>
```